# Well-posedness of gradient flows

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations, gradient-flows

For a convex lower-semicontinuous functional on a Hilbert space $I\colon H\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, it is shown in Evans' PDE that the Hilbert-space-valued ODE
$$\begin{cases}\mathbf{u}'(t)\in-\partial I[\mathbf{u}(t)]\\\mathbf{u}(0)=u\in H\end{cases}$$
is well-posed for all time, where $\partial I[\cdot]$ denotes the subdifferential. The intuition makes perfect sense, and I am wondering if there are similar results by relaxing convexity. In particular, is there a well-posedness result if $I$ is say simply bounded from below, or coercive? Intuitively it seems plausible, but I haven't been able to find a nice resource on this matter. Perhaps even a nice text on variational methods might have what I'm looking for?

Comment: MathSciNet tells me about some papers of Rossi and Savare MR2224826, and MR2148878. Taking a quick look, it seems that one of the things that breaks is uniqueness. Not sure if this is "old" enough to have made it into textbooks yet.

Comment: Thank you @WillieWong, the second article is very helpful and interesting!